# How to use values created inside a loop function?

Tags: c++

I would like to know which one would be the best way of using values created inside a loop, outside of that loop. I have for example the function:

```
void Loop(int a)
{
  // recursion loop execution
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
 {
  int new_a = a + i;
 }
}
```

I would like to use that "new_a" as it is being "looped" in another function which is plotting a graph and only needs the "yAxe" value. Like that:

```
int main ()
{
int a = 5;
plot (x,Loop(int a);
}
```

I know I could create an array with the values of the loop but I wouldn't like to store them and for big plottings would be too much memory.

Comment: `new_a` only exists inside the `for` loop so you need to store the values somewhere (and also `return` them from the function to be usable outside)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a function object, a.k.a. a *functor*? It can hold a state which is modified each time the object is "called" through an overloaded `operator()` function.

Comment: does plot alter the value of `a` during execution, or is it a read only (input) parameter?

Comment: maybe you can use the observer-pattern, so that every time the value in the loop-function has changed, the observer will be notified to plot the refreshed value

Comment: Plot doesn't alter the value of "a". It just plot it.

Answer (score 0):

Any local variable will be destroyed when the scope of them be finished. For example, in your code `new_a` will be destroyed when the for loop is finished, and the `a` is destroyed when the function be finished. I mean if you care about memory, don't be worry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call `Loop` multiple times (like e.g. `Loop(a)`) and each call you should get the next "iteration" of the loop?

That would have been easy if C++ had [*continuations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) which it doesn't. Instead it can be emulated by using classes and objects and operator overloading.

For example:

```
class LoopClass
{
public:
    LoopClass(int initial_value = 0)
        : current_value{initial_value}
    {
    }

    int operator()(int a)
    {
        return a + current_value++;
    }

private:
    int current_value;
};
```

It can be used as such:

```
LoopClass Loop;  // The value initialized with zero

int a = 5;
std::cout << "First call : " << Loop(a) << '\n';
std::cout << "Second call: " << Loop(a) << '\n';
```

The above code, if put into a program, should print

```
First call : 5
Second call: 6
```